# Using 'sed' to filter string

Tags: bash, sed

I've been trying to use sed to filter my string and return a new string with value found between two patterns of original string

For example, I would want to return "0C" from "0x0C," 
Is that possible using sed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with bash? You've included "bash" in your description and your tags, but you're asking explicitly for a solution using `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/0x\([^,]*\),/\1/' <<< "0x0C,"
```

Searches for `0x` and captures following non comma characters. Captured string is ouput using backreference.

Comment: That's not possible with macOS, which is my platform... And I need sed :(

Comment: I added a solution with sed.

Comment: The two patterns I need are "0x" from left and "," from right. "0x0c," -> "0c"

Comment: I did not see the comma... Updated.

Comment: That did it! Thanks :)

Comment: "0x0a," -> "0a" doesnt work... "0x04," -> "04" doesnt work either :(

Comment: It's perfect now. Thanks :D